# Fitting image within wrapper using overflow:hidden (CSS/ HTML/ PHP)

Tags: php, html, css

I have a directory full of product images. I am trying to display each image as `150px`x`150px` without distorting the image and place a border around the product code (which is the image name) and the image itself. This is what it looks like now:
[image]

I would like the image and product code to sit at the bottom of the border, but I am having issues because I am a noob and using `overflow:hidden`. Essentially I would like the center image to look like the other two.

Here is my `PHP` code (using `php` because I will need to access `sql` later):

```
<php
$dir = "/some/location/";
if ($opendir = opendir($dir)){
    while(($file= readdir($opendir))!== FALSE){
        if($file!="."&&$file!=".."){
            echo('<div class = "image" > ');
            echo "<img src='/some/location/$file'><br>";
            $sku = substr($file,0,-4);
            echo("<p>");
            echo($sku);
            echo("</p>");
            echo("</div>");} } }
?>
```

`CSS` Code:

```
<style>
div.image {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 170px;
        width: 170px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: green;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 10px auto;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;    }

    div.image img {
        max-height: 135px;
        max-width: 135px;
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 25px;    }
</style>
```

Comment: Why do you include your PHP code? The question has nothing to do with PHP, just give us the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `position: relative;` to your outer (wrapper container, with borders). Then wrap image and text beneath in a div and set it's css like this:

```
.image-wrap {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
}
```

It should do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

Nikolav's answer works well (although, you don't need to set all those properties in the .image-wrap div -- position and bottom will achieve your goal), but if you don't want to add that extra wrapper div to your HTML you can just absolutely position both the p and the img inside of your .image container div.

You'd give your p a bottom of 0px:

```
    p {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
```

You'd then need to know the height of your p element, so that you can give your img a bottom of at least that, so that it sits above the p. If your p is 20px high then you'd use:

```
    .image img {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 20px;
    }
```